# Chrome Extension not accepting localhost php file

Tags: php, google-chrome-extension

As i was building a simple chrome extension it is not working with button click, when i click on the "Go" button it's not able to access the localhost file script.php seems to be also not displaying any errors too. Can anyone get me out of this issue? And can anyone predict where i have gone wrong?

This is my manifest.json file

```
{
"manifest_version": 2,
"name": "Extension",
"description": "Extension for scraping",

"icons": {"128":"icon.png" },
"browser_action":{
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "pop.html"
},
"version": "1.0.0",
"permissions": [
    "http://localhost/*"
]
}
```

pop.html

```
<body>
<form action="http://localhost/db/script.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="your name.."><br>
    <input type="text" name="email" placeholder="your email.."><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Go" name="submit">
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

localhost- script.php

```
<?php
    $name=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
    $email=mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
    if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
        echo 'Success';
        die();
    }
    $bridge=mysqli_connect('localhost','root','','exten');
    $query="INSERT INTO info (name,email) VALUES ('$name','$email'))";
    if($bridge->query($query)){
        echo 'Added';       
    }
?>
```

Comment: The `form` element is redirecting the popup from its internal chrome-extension:// URL to your localhost web page, which isn't what you want to do, I think. Submit the form manually using `fetch` or `XMLHttpRequest` and send the data using `FormData` API. And remove the `<form>` element or do preventDefault in the submit event listener.